# Хороший учебник по C++

Tags: c++, книги

Когда учил Visual Basic, очень помогла книга "MS Visual Basic 6.0. Шаг за шагом." Доступно написана, сразу работаем с окнами и т.д. Однако по С++ вообще нормальной книги наподобие той не нашлось. Может, все-таки кто-то знает понятную книгу по С++, чтобы делать оконные приложения?

Вот нашел C++ для начинающих - серия Шаг за шагом. Шилд.

Comment: Обратите внимание на темы:

 * [Хорошая книга для начала (MS Visual C++)][1]
 * [Обучение C++ с нуля][2]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/29229
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/27099

Comment: Самый нормальный учебник тот который ты поймешь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. )) 
Я и говорю о том чтобы найти учебник который мне бы было проще понять и сразу писать оконные приложения, а не консольные. Пример учебника по Бэйсику уже привел. Вот на подобие такого только по С++.

Comment: Мих, вот объясни, чего ты умничаешь постоянно? =) Ну серьезно.

Comment: @knes Я не умничаю, я просто ответил, потому, что то что вы предлагаете те учебники которые  Вы понимаете не значит что его поймет другой человек поэтому говорю что лучший ученик тот который Вы понимаете, а учебников по С++ до фига.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 4):

С++ более "серьезный" язык, чем VB. Сначала надо разобраться с идеологией, основами синтаксиса, принципами реализации ООП в нем, а это лучше делать, создавая для начала консольные программки, и уже потом осваивать работу с GUI.

Сам учил по Стивен Прата "Язык программирования С++". Весьма рекомендую. Он дает хорошие знания по общим понятиям языка без привязки к конкретной платформе. Для начала лучше работать не в VisualStudio, а в среде попроще, типа Dev-Cpp (для обучения весьма недурная IDE) или даже в блокноте+консоль+компилятор. И уже потом переходить к VS.

Cтрауструп - великолепная книга, но для новичка сложновата. Керниган-Ритчи - классическая книга по языку С (а не С++). Мне лично не очень понравилась.

Comment: блокноте+консоль+компилятор, ИМХОдля новичка самый оптимальный вариант

Comment: Да. Но только после gterminal линя вид консоли виндов вызывает у меня чувство тошноты.

Answer (score 1):

В своё время начинал с этих книг:

> Борис Пахомов. "C/C++ и MS Visual C++
> 2008 для начинающих"
>
> Лаптев В.В. "C++.
> Объектно-ориентированное
> программирование"

Answer (score 0):

Р.Лафоре Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++

Comment: Спасибо. Какие еще кроме этой вам помогл? Мне показалась она сложноватой. Или не интересной. В том смысле, что в книге "Шаг за шагом" Весь синтаксис и правила рассматривались во время создания программы. А тут как-то сначала описывается а затем применяется...

Comment: Страуструп и Керниган/Риччи... Они вас устроят меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Дэвис Чепмен -- Изучи Ms Visual C++.NET за 21 день (Если нужно учить оконный интерфейс с нуля, эта -- в самый раз)

Павловская, Щупак -- С/С++ (Там две книги: практикум и собственно теоретический материал

Страуструп -- Полное руководство по С/С++ (Между прочим, очень понятно все написано)

Все три книги я читал, и с нуля учить С/С++ по ним есть очень хорошо. ИМХО...